# How to deallocate memory of Python List Object in C using ctypes?

Tags: python, c, memory-leaks, ctypes

I am using `ctypes` to import a piece of C code into my Python code. the code is as follows:

- test.h

```
#include "Python.h"
#include <stdio.h>

PyObject *getPosNodeFeature();
```

- test.c

```
#include "test.h"

#ifdef _WIN32
#define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define API
#endif

API PyObject *getPosNodeFeature(){
    const wchar_t *beforeWordTmp = L"bl";
    wchar_t *beforeWordPartRight = malloc(2 * sizeof(wchar_t));
    wcsncpy(beforeWordPartRight, beforeWordTmp, 2);

    PyObject *beforeWordPartRightTmp = PyUnicode_FromWideChar(beforeWordPartRight, i);
    PyObject *beforeRightWordsList = PyList_New(0);

    ret = PyList_Append(beforeRightWordsList, beforeWordPartRightTmp);
    
    Py_DECREF(beforeWordPartRightTmp);
    free(beforeWordPartRight);
    beforeWordPartRight = NULL;

    Py_DECREF(beforeRightWordsList);
    
    PyObject *featureList = PyList_New(0);

    return featureList;
}
```

- in the above code, I introduced a temp `PyListObject` -> `beforeRightWordsList`. This object is processed and deallocated.
- then I compiled it and included into the python code.
- test.py

```
import os
import ctypes

dir_path = '/path/to/libtest.so'
feature_extractor = ctypes.PyDLL(os.path.join(dir_path, 'libtest.so'))
get_pos_node_feature_c = feature_extractor.getPosNodeFeature
get_pos_node_feature_c.argtypes = []
get_pos_node_feature_c.restype = ctypes.py_object

for i in range(10000):
    res = get_pos_node_feature_c()
```

- When I run the code above, I find the memory of the python process increasing in comply with the for loop.
- So, how to release the memory of the `PyListObject`? Simply de-count-referencing it is not enough?

Comment: I built a debug version and checked `sys.gettotalrefcount()` after calling your function.  It is reference counting correctly and I don't see a leak.  Can't reproduce.

Comment: FYI, in your example, `i` and `ret` weren't defined.  I used `2` for `i` and removed `ret` in my build to get it to compile.

Comment: Hey, bro. Thank you very much for your help. The question above may be not clear. And the whole C code is in [posFeatureExtractor.c](https://github.com/dongrixinyu/jiojio/blob/master/jiojio/jiojio_cpp/posFeatureExtractor.c) and the python code is in [test_pos_cpp.py](https://github.com/dongrixinyu/jiojio/blob/master/jiojio/jiojio_cpp/test_pos_cpp.py). And in the python debug mode, I checked the results to be still increasing with the loop. Could you do me a favor to check my C code please? And I can not find where the ref count increases. Thx again!

Comment: I see `sys.gettotalrefcount()` go down, not a memory leak, but an invalid `Py_DECREF`. I was crashing when the object that was mistakenly decremented was freed. Comment out line 212 `Py_DECREF(curWord);` in `posFeatureExtractor.c`. `curWord` is the result of `PyList_GetItem` and was a borrowed reference, so shouldn't be decremented. Then I got stable counts. Debug hint: don't save the return value of the call. It adds references. If you call the function and don't save the return value, the total reference count should be stable you have side effects mutating input parameters. 希望这对你帮助

Comment: 我不是中国人但是我会说一点点汉语。I also moved the ref count immediately before and after the call. Python does some caching so some changes are expected, but each time through the loop the number should be stable. I can post the numbers I got if you like

Comment: Thank you so much! I ll try by myself later.